# SVG sprite в псевдоэлементе ::before

Tags: css, svg, спрайт

Имеется svg спрайт с иконками, как можно реализовать вставку иконку в ::before не отдельным файлом-иконкой *.svg, а вытащить уже имеющуюся из спрайта?

Comment: Под свг-спрайтом вы что понимаете?

Comment: Спрайт из svg иконок. Не совсем понимаю вопрос.

Comment: приведите примерный код этого спрайта. есть несколько техник его создания.

Comment: http://www.flaticon.com/svg-sprites отсюда

Comment: Иконки из спрайта, сделанного таким образом, применять к псевдоэлементам нельзя, насколько мне известно.

Comment: Спасибо, опробую другие методы создания @sasha-omelchenko